# iOS swift UITableView with section is not displaying data properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i am working on an app in which i have to display UITableView with sections

i created 2 arrays
commentArr - For comments data

replyArray - for reply data

Here is my api response

```
"posts_review": [
            {
                "id": "87",
                "name": "Pr****ha",
                "email": "test@gmail.com",
                "comment":"\�\�\�\�\�\�\�\�\�\�\�\�\�\�\�\�\�\�",
                "post_id": "357",
                "created_at": "2023-05-29 05:57:11",
                "rating": null,
                "user_id": "1405",
                "status": "1",
                "review_id": "0",
                "reply": [],
                "image": "image1683887192.png"
            },
            {
                "id": "71",
                "name": "sidd",
                "email": "ab@abc.com",
                "comment": "hello",
                "post_id": "357",
                "created_at": "2023-05-27 09:22:02",
                "rating": null,
                "user_id": "469",
                "status": "1",
                "review_id": "0",
                "reply": [
                    {
                        "id": "78",
                        "name": "Ab*****ap",
                        "email": null,
                        "comment": "test reply....2",
                        "post_id": null,
                        "created_at": "2023-05-29 03:06:17",
                        "rating": null,
                        "user_id": "464",
                        "status": "1",
                        "review_id": "71",
                        "image": "image1675080770.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "92",
                        "name": "sha",
                        "email": null,
                        "comment": null,
                        "post_id": null,
                        "created_at": "2023-05-29 06:12:18",
                        "rating": null,
                        "user_id": "1405",
                        "status": "1",
                        "review_id": "71",
                        "image": "image1683887192.png"
                    }
                ],
                "image": "image1683887192.png"
            },
            {
                "id": "64",
                "name": "Ab******ap",
                "email": "ab@abc.com",
                "comment": "This is test",
                "post_id": "357",
                "created_at": "2023-05-25 01:05:57",
                "rating": null,
                "user_id": "464",
                "status": "1",
                "review_id": "0"
            },
            {
                "id": "63",
                "name": "Ab.......",
                "email": "ab@abc.com",
                "comment": "This is test",
                "post_id": "357",
                "created_at": "2023-05-25 01:05:53",
                "rating": null,
                "user_id": "464",
                "status": "1",
                "review_id": "0",
                "reply": [],
                "image": "image1675080770.jpg"
            }
        ]
```

I need to display it as comments in header and their reply in cells

Please suggest me some code how to achieve this in `UITableView`

I tried this code

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        print("CommentArray Count is --", self.commentArr.count)
        return self.commentArr.count
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        print("replyArray Count is --", self.replyArray.count)
        return self.replyArray.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = commentTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CommenrTVC") as! CommenrTVC
        
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.commentTable.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        
        cell.nameLbl.text = self.replyArray[indexPath.section]["name"].string ?? ""
       
        let dateStr = self.replyArray[indexPath.section]["created_at"].string ?? ""
        cell.dateLbl.text = dateStr
        
        //cell.commentLbl.text = self.commentArr[indexPath.row]["comment"].string ?? ""
        let commentStrr = self.replyArray[indexPath.section]["comment"].string ?? ""
        
        
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Comments and its replies are interrelated you should declare only one array which will store posts_review array from response.

```
var arrPostComments : [postReviewArray]?
```

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        print("CommentArray Count is --", arrPostComments.count)
        return arrPostComments.count ?? 0
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("replyArray Count is --", arrPostComments[indexPath.section].reply.count)
        return arrPostComments?[indexPath.section].reply.count ?? 0
    }
```

Comment: post_review are added to commentArr